# Change Marker icon API google maps v3 with a select

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have this problem,
I made some select options in html and each one has the name of an icon image in the value:

```
<select onchange="function()"> // i haven't got the function yet
    <option value="green.png">green</option> 
    <option value="orange.png">orange</option> 
    <option value="teal.png">teal</option> 
</select>
```

And the current javascript code:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

 <!-- Control Bar -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ZoomPanControl.js"></script>
 <!-- Control Bar -->

     <script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-32.818044,-61.395249);
    // Map Options
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
    // Map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  var ZoomPanControl = new missouristate.web.ZoomPanControl(map);
        ZoomPanControl.index = -1;
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(ZoomPanControl);
}
    // Directions
function codeAddress() {
var cañada = 'Cañada de Gomez, Argentina';
var altura = document.getElementById('altura').value;
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value + altura + cañada  ;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    // MARKER
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Error: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

// Listener 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

And I need to change the icon of the last created marker (just the last one) when the user selects one or another option in the select.  I don't know if I need a listener or I can do it with just the "onchange" event.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make the marker global
2. call setIcon on it in your change the icon function

   ```
   var marker = null;
   function codeAddress() {
     var cañada = 'Cañada de Gomez, Argentina';
     var altura = document.getElementById('altura').value;
     var address = document.getElementById('address').value + altura + cañada  ;
     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
         // MARKER
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           map: map,
           position: results[0].geometry.location
         });
       } else {
         alert('Error: ' + status);
       }
     });
   }

   <select onchange="marker.setIcon(this.value)">
     <option value="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png">green</option> 
     <option value="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/orange-dot.png">orange</option> 
     <option value="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png">yellow</option> 
   </select>
   ```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_changeMarkerBySelect.html)