# issues with changing color of google map api markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've looked at all the suggestions from previously asked questions similar to mine, as well as following the google maps api developers info page on overlays, but no answers have helped - I'm trying to simply change the color of the markers from the standard to green, but every time I try and add fillColor, etc. to my code it either won't show the marker or won't show the map at all. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
    function createMap() {
        // map options
        var options = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.909736, -98.522109), // centered US
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false
        };

        // init map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);
    }

    function addMarker() {
    fetchNewQuote();
    var indext;
    for (indext = 0; indext <array.length; ++indext) {
        splitarr = array[indext].split(":");
        geosplit = splitarr[1].split(", ");
        if (indext < 50) {
        $('#tweet_table').append(array[indext] + "</br></br>");
        }          
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(geosplit[0], geosplit[1]),
            map: map,
            title: 'Click me to see what this individual tweeted!' 
          });

          (function(marker, splitarr, indext) {
              var tweetclick = "TOBACCO VISUALIZATION</br>" + "Keyword: " + splitarr[0] + "</br> Coordinates: " + splitarr[1] + "</br> Tweet: " + splitarr[2];
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content: tweetclick
                  });
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
              });
          })(marker, splitarr, indext);
          marker.setMap(map);
          markersArray.push(marker);
        }
    }
```

Comment: fillColor doesn't apply to markers. Please see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions).  [A recent question about changing marker colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392077/change-marker-icon-api-google-maps-v3-with-a-select/18393215#18393215) (with an example...)

Answer (score 0):

You can load your own marker like this :

```
var icon = https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|00FF00
```

You have to pass the color of the marker at RGB format after the pipe. If you want a blue marker, just pass 0000FF instead of 00FF00.

Then, use it like this :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(geosplit[0], geosplit[1]),
                map: map,
                title: 'Click me to see what this individual tweeted!' 
                icon: icon
            });
```

Hope this helps !